# MIPS Assembly subroutines & stacks, Exception 5 bad data address, Exception 7 address error in store

Tags: exception, assembly, mips, subroutine, stack-frame

I'm trying to figure out some stack frame business with assembly, and i admittingly have little idea what i'm doing... but i think i'm close?

My program calls a subroutine that counts down from 10 and then quits. This actually seems to work fine, but i'm receiving some exception errors.

## Here's my output

[image]

## Here is my code:

```
main: ######################################################################

    ################### SAVE STACK ###################

    subu $sp, $sp, 32           # create 32 byte stack frame

    ########## save ra and fp
    sw $ra, 0($sp)              # save return address
    sw $fp, 4($sp)              # save frame pointer

    #addu $fp, $sp, 28          # setup new frame pointer ?????

    ########## save general purpose registers

    sw $s0, 8($s0)              # save counter 

    ##################################################

    ########## Begin Message
    li, $v0, 4                  # sys call #4, print string
    la, $a0, STR_BEGIN          # load string
    syscall                     # execute call

    li, $s0, 10                 # init loop counter

    ########## Print Starting Point
    li $v0, 1                   # sys call #1, print int
    move $a0, $s0               # load starting count
    syscall                     # execute call

    ########## Call Subroutine
    jal subroutine              # call subroutine
    # print something to show when it returns

    ########## END Message
    #li, $v0, 4                 # sys call #4, print string
    #la, $a0, STR_END           # load string
    #syscall                    # execute call

    ################## RESTORE STACK #################

    ########## restore general purpose registers
    lw $s0, 8($sp)              # restore counter

    ########## restore ra and fp
    lw $ra, 0($sp)              # restore return address
    lw $fp, 4($sp)              # restore frame pointer

    addu $fp, $sp, 32           # restore callers stack pointer

    ##################################################

ending:    jr $31               # stop the program, why does this loop if i uncomment the above syscall?

subroutine: ######################################################################

    ################### SAVE STACK ###################

    subu $sp, $sp, 32           # create 32 byte stack frame

    ########## save ra and fp
    sw $ra, 0($sp)              # save return address
    sw $fp, 4($sp)              # save frame pointer

    addu $fp, $sp, 28           # setup new frame pointer ?????? why am i doing this?

    ########## save general purpose registers

    sw $s0, 8($s0)              # save counter 

    ##################################################

    sub $s0, $s0, 1             # decrement by one

    ########## Count Down
    li, $v0, 4                  # sys call #4, print string
    la, $a0, STR_ELIPS          # load string
    syscall                     # execute call

    li $v0, 1                   # sys call #1, print int
    move $a0, $s0               # load starting count
    syscall                     # print output

    ########## subroutine condition
    bgt $s0, 0, subroutine      # if count < 10, then loop  

    ################## RESTORE STACK #################

    ########## restore general purpose registers
    lw $s0, 8($sp)              # restore counter

    ########## restore ra and fp
    lw $ra, 0($sp)              # restore return address
    lw $fp, 4($sp)              # restore frame pointer

    addu $fp, $sp, 32           # restore callers stack pointer

    ##################################################

    jr  $ra                     # return to caller

# END subroutine ######################################################################
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first obvious error I could spot was your

```
sw $s0, 8($s0)              # save counter
```

line (2 occurrences). You probably wanted `sw $s0, 8($sp)` given that you restore `s0` from there later. Fix that and use a debugger to find further errors if any.

Update: also this is wrong:

```
addu $fp, $sp, 32           # restore callers stack pointer
```

Should probably be `addu $sp, $sp, 32`.

Comment: Thanks, the first mistake i made with the counter fixed all errors. The second change doesn't seem to affect the program either way. My output looks much better, but now when my subroutine quits, it prints the message right before my $jr 31 program exit 10 times.

Comment: Sounds like it's not saving my return address correctly, but i'm saving and restoring it like im supposed to, or how i think i'm supposed to anyways.

Comment: Furthermore `bgt $s0, 0, subroutine` should not jump back to the start of the function because that'll do the whole frame setup thing again. You should just jump back to the printing loop that you have marked with `Count Down`